# Create ad rotator windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I was using AdRotator with my Windows Phone 7.5 Apps, but with Windows Phone 8 is not working properly.
So I am trying to create just a simple ad rotator that will change between 2 ads.
Each ad is located in an usercontrol but my problem is how can I make them to be displayed randomly 50% 50% chances the 2 usercontrol?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int ad = rnd.Next(2);

if ( ad == 0 )
{
 ShowAd1();
}
else
{
 ShowAd2();
}
```

Huh?